# Ad custom admin page like WordPress customizer

Tags: menus, pages, wp-admin, admin

Is it possible to create a empty page (completely empty without sidebar, ...) in admin panel.

Something similar to WordPress customizer (.../wp-admin/customize.php) page: .../wp-admin/builder.php

The builder.php file should point to a file in the plugin.

I tried add add_submenu_page and other relevant functions but none of them give me the ability.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I'm not sure, that I understand your goal correctly. But I use the Customizer for UI Settings of plugins, in the area of the admin, also possible for admin area which your items. You find my idea here (https://github.com/bueltge/customizer-sandbox) as public development, maybe this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the plugin, but I need to create something which is separated fully from the default Customiser.